# CSS @media print to change td tag not working

Tags: css

I have an rows of data which has several columns. I have name columns to be wider than the rest.

Following are my codes where during printing, the ID field expand_field be wider, but there are no effects in @media print CSS.

```
@media print {          
#expand_field td {
    width: 500px;
}                     
echo '<td id="expand_field">'.$rows["3"].'</td>';
```

Answer (score 3):

Your selector is wrong:

Since td has id you should do like this:

```
@media print {          
td#expand_field{
    width: 500px;
}
```

But since id is unique you can just use that id

```
@media print {          
#expand_field{
    width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: `display: none` working like this `#expand_field { display: none; }` I actually want wider `#expand_field { width: 500px; }`. The width of td remains same.